# Switching Wiris http to https

Tags: plugins

We have implemented the Wiris tool into an application, but when you open the editor in Chrome for example you need to click the shield and select 'Load unsafe script' each time. As a note the application it is integrated with is https.

[image]

I know that when you inspect the tool there are three links in the markup:

http://www.wiris.net/demo/editor/editor?lang=en

http://www.wiris.com/editor3/docs/manual/latex-support

http://www.wiris.com/editor3/docs/manual

I can only assume that because these are http they are triggering the security option each time the editor is opened. Does anyone know if it is possible to launch the editor with https so that it can be used more efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the configuration.ini file for WIRIS there is a variable called `wirisimageserviceprotocol`.

You could try setting the value of that to `https` like this:

```
wirisimageserviceprotocol = https
```

**Reference:** [WIRIS Configuration](http://www.wiris.com/en/plugins/docs/resources/configuration-table)